# Maven exec plugin execution conundrum

Tags: maven, exec

Sample maven build file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>my-validation-one</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>echo</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>"My validation one"</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>my-validation-two</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>echo</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>"My validation two"</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Sample maven output:

```
$ mvn install
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_20/bin/java -classpath C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1 org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher "install"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - test:test:jar:1.0.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: my-validation-one}]
[INFO] "My validation two"
[INFO] [exec:exec {execution: my-validation-two}]
[INFO] "My validation two"
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
<snip>
```

Shouldn't my-validation-one echo "My validation one" to the console?  Why does it seem like maven is getting its wires crossed?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `configuration` specific to the `execution` within the `execution` block. Then it should work correctly.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>my-validation-two</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
           <executable>echo</executable>
           <arguments>
              <argument>"My validation two"</argument>
           </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Also, if both the `executions` are bound to same `phase` and `goal`, you can combine then within `executions` block instead of declaring the `plugin` twice.

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  I must have misinterpreted the documentation.  Can you explain in plain English what affect the improper configuration had on the maven build?  It seems as if the bad configuration masks the second plugin declaration.  Could that tag arrangement, being syntactically correct, ever be useful?  The former to me reads "Configuration of the plugin" while the later reads "Configuration of the execution of the plugin".  How would you know to use one over the other, other than correctly interpreting the documentation, if they are both syntactically correct?

Comment: Just found where I got my information.  From the exec:exec [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) it says that the <executions> and <configuration> tags are peers, not nested.  Maybe this is a case of stale documentation?